# Amount of ammunition typically carried by an C18th British redcoat

Tags: 18th-century

How many rounds of musket ammunition did the typical British redcoat carry during the C18th & Napoleonic wars?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [HERE](https://www.tumblr.com/search/bayoneted%20muskets)

```
Sir,

Agreeable to Major General Mathew’s Order I send a Return of the Deficiencies
in the Seventeenth Company. We have at present one Cartridge Box for each man, 
but as they hold eighteen Rounds only I shall be extremely thankfull for an Order
to compleat us to two per man.


I am Sir
with great Respect
Your most Obedt.
Humble Servant

George Cuppaidge
Capt. 17th Infy.”
```

So 18-36 rounds (if they had 2).  The US Civil War cartridge box capacity was 40 rounds, as this was a Corps Symbol for one of the Western Armies.

Comment: The 17th were captured and re-issued with a government set with 18 holes after Stoney Point. An early american war of independence battalion box held 29 cartridges. Sergeants often held secondary pouches for dishing out during an engagement. (See 'With Zeal and Bayonet Only' by Matthew Spring. Also, good choice of reference - I actually re-enact the 17th Regiment!)

Answer (score 6):

According to Major Adye's "Bombardier and Pocket Gunner" (2nd ed., London, 1802, page7)

> The cartouche boxes of the [British] infantry are made of so many
>   shapes and sizes, that it is impossible to say exactly what ammunition
>   they may contain, but most of them can carry 60 rounds.

Also a table on page 79, notes that musket cartridges were carried in 'bundles' of 10.

Given the date of publication, it should apply to the infantrymen fighting during the Napoleonic Wars, at least.

Edit:

It would seem that the value of 60 rounds per man is confirmed by a general order (issued by the Duke of Wellington) at Villa Del Toro, 27th Sept 1812 which states

> The stores of musket ammunition are necessarily limited, and the state
>   of them is founded upon the certainty that every soldier has at all
>   times in his possession sixty rounds

taken from ["The General Orders of Field Marshal, the Duke of Wellington in Portugal, Spain and France from 1809 to 1814"](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=C_KgAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA8#v=onepage&q&f=false) (London, 1837, pg 8)

Edit2:

Bryan Fosten's "Wellington's Infantry 1" (Osprey Publishing, London, 1992, pg 24) gives the following description of the infantryman's cartridges stowage.

> The [cartridge] pouch was fitted with a tin or wooden box split
>   honeycomb-fashion into small rectangular sections into which the
>   separate cartridges were inserted: 36 seems to have been the normal
>   number...In the field an additional 24 cartridges could be carried in
>   a 'magazine', a tin case covered in black leather carried 'on buff
>   belts and buckles'

Which again, gives a total of 60 cartridges per man.

Comment: Cartouche boxes are larger capacity boxes carried on the ammo wagons in the rear. The personal load was carried in smaller boxes.

Comment: According to Adye; "[Ammunition] is generally packed in half barrels containing 1000 musquet[sic], or 1500 carbine cartridges. An ammunition wagon will carry 20 of these barrels and an ammunition cart will carry 12 of them." So if the wagon is carrying barrels of cartridges, why decant them into cartouche boxes? It stikes me that the author means the term to be a "cartridge case" that's issued to the soldiers. His number certainly correspond to Wellington's general order.

Comment: The info I found, including a period letter is that the cartridge boxes held 18 rounds only. Cartouche boxes might be used to carry from barrels to the line for refilling cartridge boxes.

Comment: Given that, in terms of ammunition, a cartouche and a cartridge are essentially the same thing, I believe that Adye was simply using the words interchangably. As he said these boxes came in a variety of shapes and sizes. Also the document you quoted was from 1780, while my references are all from the Napoleonic period, some 20-35 years later. It could easily be that as a result of the experiences in the American Revolutionary War, the British Army changed the ammunition allocation per soldier.